# Looking to get information from two different tiers of nested lists

Tags: c#, linq, nested-lists

I'm trying to streamline a query using 2 foreach loops using LINQ.

I have the following code:

```
// Create a dictionary of all the pets where the key is building # + owner name + pet's age
Dictionary<string, Pet> petDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Pet>();
        foreach (Tenant tenant in allTenants){
            foreach (Pet pet in tenant.PetList){
                petDictionary.Add(tenant.BuildingNumber  + "-" + tenant.Name + "-" + pet.Age, pet);
            }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Pet> petKvp in petDictionary){
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0,20} | secret Id: {1}", petKvp.Value.Name, petKvp.Key);  
        }
```

The code works but I'd like to use ToDictionary to replace the nested foreach loops above. Would someone let me know how to do this using LINQ?

I've tried a couple things but I can't find out how to get information from both the tenant list AND the pet list in the same LINQ query.

Tenant Class:

```
public class Tenant
{
    // Attributes
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    public int BuildingNumber{ get; set;}
    public List<Pet> PetList{get; set;}
}
```

Pet Class:

```
public class Pet
{
    // Attributes
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    public int Age{ get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ and produce a new dictionary without declaring your dictionary before hand and adding items to it.

```
public void CombineTenatsAndPets()
{
    //Create data
    var tenants = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => new Tenant()
    {
        PetList = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(_ => new Pet()).ToList()
    });

    var tenantsAndPets = tenants
        .SelectMany(t =>
            t.PetList.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, Pet>(
                    $"{t.BuildingNumber}-{t.Name}-{p.Age}", p)))
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you much! The compiler didn't like $"{t.BuildingNumber}-{t.Name}-{p.Age}, something about the $.  I changed it to (tenant.BuildingNumber + "-" + tenant.Name + "-" + pet.Age, pet) and it worked.